# How to ADD specific values in a oracle database column?

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle, replace

i have a emp table like below

```
id  name    value
1   a       hel
2   b       dev2
3   c       new3
4   d       can6
5   e       kun8
6   f       luv4
```

i want to add a string in particular location like below for value column

```
id  name    value
1   a       hel
2   b       devqwe2
3   c       newqwe3
4   d       canqwe6
5   e       kunqwe8
6   f       luvqwe4
```

please any one help me while select query

Comment: Which values to update? Is it length > 3, or ending with a digit, or something else?

Comment: What about a value of `kun123` should that become `kunqwe123` or `kun12qwe3`?

Comment: @jarlh i want to end with digit

Comment: Again: what if it ends with 3 digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `regexp_replace()` to insert `'qwe'` just before the final digit(s), if any:

```
select 
    id, 
    name, 
    case when regexp_like(value, '\d+$')
        then regexp_replace(value, '^(\w+)(\d+)$', '\1' || 'qwe' || '\2')
        else value
    end value
from emp
```

If `value` ends with digits, `regexp_replace()` inserts `'qwe'` before the digits. If not, `value` is left untouched.

If you want an `update`:

```
update emp
set value = regexp_replace(value, '^(\w+)(\d+)$', '\1' || 'qwe' || '\2')
where regexp_like(value, '\d+$')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=28c19c37173e4f4b7682d6a80d07aa7f)**:

```
ID | NAME | VALUE  
-: | :--- | :------
 1 | a    | hel    
 2 | b    | devqwe2
 3 | c    | newqwe3
 4 | d    | canqwe6
 5 | e    | kunqwe8
 6 | f    | luvqwe4
```

Comment: I'd add a WHERE clause, to keep unchanged rows out of transaction.

Comment: @jarlh: yes it was unclear whether OP wants a `select` or an `update`. I added an `update` query to my answer (with a `where` clause).

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE`, right?

```
update emp set
  value = case when id = 2 then 'devqwe2'
               when id = 3 then 'newqwe3'
               etc.
          end;
```

I don't see any pattern which would allow you to do it *automatically* (or, at least, it isn't obvious to me). If there is a rule which leads from *source* to *target*, explain it.

**[EDIT, after seeing @a_horse's comment; quite obvious, if you pay attention ...]**

```
SQL> WITH emp (id, name, VALUE)
  2       AS (SELECT 1, 'a', 'hel' FROM DUAL
  3           UNION ALL
  4           SELECT 2, 'b', 'dev2' FROM DUAL
  5           UNION ALL
  6           SELECT 3, 'c', 'new3' FROM DUAL)
  7  SELECT id,
  8         name,
  9         VALUE,
 10         CASE
 11            WHEN REGEXP_LIKE (VALUE, '\d$')
 12            THEN
 13                  REGEXP_SUBSTR (VALUE, '^[[:alpha:]]+')
 14               || 'qwe'
 15               || REGEXP_SUBSTR (VALUE, '\d+$')
 16            ELSE
 17               VALUE
 18         END
 19            new_value
 20    FROM emp;

        ID N VALU NEW_VALUE
---------- - ---- -----------
         1 a hel  hel
         2 b dev2 devqwe2
         3 c new3 newqwe3

SQL>
```

Comment: I think the pattern is: put `qwe` before the digit at the end.

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged `replace` in the question so i suggest the answer accordingly :

```
SELECT REPLACE(t.value, 'dev2', 'devqwe2'),
       REPLACE(t.value, 'new3', 'newqwe3')
etc...
  FROM emp t
```

But still if you can tell us the pattern of changing the values rule then it can avoid to write many replace statement

Or

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (t.value, '^(\w+)(\d+)$', '\1' || 'qwe' || '\2')
FROM emp t where regexp_like(t.value, '\d+$');
```